# MySQL items of an order without primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key

i have two tables in my database which belongs to each other.
mp_order and mp_order_items.

**mp_order** has the main informations of an order of a customer like adress, date etc.
(*order_id, customer_company, customer_name, customer_adress, order_date, ... [etc.]*)

**mp_order_items** has the priducts/items which was ordered
(*order_id, item_id, item_qty*)

Due to order_id and item_id can repeat (but not in combination) i cant set one column as primary key.
Should i implement another column as unique identifier for the single entries or is it valid to have a table without primary key?

Comment: Set both order_id and item_id as primary key, eg.`Primary key(item_id, order_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Define a primary key on `(order_id, item_id)`
- Define a synthetic primary key, such as an auto-incremented column.

I prefer the second method.  It is more flexible for the future:

- Perhaps an order could contain the same items, but with different pricing or shipping addresses or shipping times.
- The rows are uniquely defined with a single number, which makes it easier to find them if you need to modify rows in the future.
- The rows are more easily referenced in another table, for instance, if you had a returns table or if the items.

Of course, having a composite primary key also works and is a very viable method for implementing the logic as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you requirement is that `order_id` and `item_id` can not repeat in combination meaning: (ord_134, itm_123) can't repeat itself then, I believe you need to create a [COMPOSITE KEY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_key).

`PRIMARY KEY(order_id, item_id)`

Basically, a combination of both Order Id and Item Id is what will uniquely identify a record in the table.
There is a caveat, if required, while defining a FOREIGN KEY, you can't link the tables using just order_id. You will need to include all the columns that are part of the COMPOSITE KEY inside the FOREIGN KEY relation.